# Implement Zoom functionality in Slick slider

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have implemented slick slider in the project.

Whenever I select on the second slider thumbnail, the first slider will work appropriately.

I want on Zoom functionality on hover on every image in the first slider that is a regular slider.

Also I have to place small thumbnail slider on left of the regular slider.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(".regular").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    autoPlay: true
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 0,
    slidesToScroll: 0,
    asNavFor: '.regular',
    dots: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    arrows: false,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
    }
    .slider-nav img{width: 15%;display: inline-block !important;float: left;margin: 10px 8px;}
</style>

    <section class="slider regular">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
        </div>
        <!-- <div> -->
          <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6"> -->
        <!-- </div> -->
      </section>
      <section class="slider slider-nav">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
     </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as

```
.slider.regular img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

would do the job to scale your image on hover. You can add `transition` effect if you need.

```js
$(".regular").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    autoPlay: true
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 0,
    slidesToScroll: 0,
    asNavFor: '.regular',
    dots: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    arrows: false,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
    }
    .slider-nav img{width: 15%;display: inline-block !important;float: left;margin: 10px 8px;}

    .slider.regular img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
</style>

    <section class="slider regular">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
        </div>
        <!-- <div> -->
          <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6"> -->
        <!-- </div> -->
      </section>
      <section class="slider slider-nav">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
     </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```